# Animação em imagem SVG - Auto Desenho

Tags: css, svg, animação

Criei uma vetor no Illustrator e o salvei em `.svg` - esse é o presente e futuro das imagens.

E peguei o código em `svg` da imagem e coloquei no site.
Eu quero fazer uma animação com essa imagem, uma animação como nesse exemplo:

http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/path.html

Onde a imagem já existe, mas ela é desenhada ao passo que faço um `scroll` na página. Eu já tenho o `skrollr.js` no meu código, uso em outros objetos. Mas no caso esse `svg` não estou conseguindo.

Nem precisa ser esse plugin, estou interessado apenas no efeito do desenho sendo feito gradativamente ao invés de aparecer a imagem por completo.

Se não deu para entender muito bem, eu vou explicando de uma forma melhor.

---

Estou quase conseguindo fazer o auto desenho, porém, em determinado ponto da animação, o desenho volta atrás. A animação faz o contorno, mas quando acaba volta o contorno. Não peguei a manha do negócio ainda. `SVG` é algo novo para mim.

```
svg{
    display: block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    .path {
        fill-opacity: 0;
        stroke: #133754;
        fill: #133754;
        stroke-width: 1;
        stroke-dasharray: 0 1014;
        stroke-dashoffset: 1014;
        animation: draw 10s forwards linear;
    }
}

@keyframes draw {
    98%{
        stroke-dashoffset: 0; 
        stroke-dasharray: 1014 0;
        fill-opacity: 0;
    }
    100%{
        fill-opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

---

Fiz de um jeito diferente agora. Atualizei o código acima de acordo com uns que vi pela internet, porém, não entendo sua síntaxe.

```
stroke-dashoffset: 0;
stroke-dasharray: 1014 0;
```

Não sei o que significa os valores.

Answer (score 1):

Então, Zoom, [stroke-dasharray](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_stroking.asp) é usado para criar traços no svg. O [stroke-dashoffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dashoffset) controla o tamanho desse traço, possibilitando a animação da linha. Perceba que, no exemplo que você mostrou, o stroke-dashoffset começa com o valor de 6000, idêntico ao valor aplicado ao stroke-dasharray. A medida que que você rola a página o script reduz o valor do stroke-dashoffset até zero, exibindo a linha. É desta forma que deve proceder a animação.